# Is it possible to modify a Product's ProductClass programmatically without duplicating the Product's ProductAttributeValues in django-oscar?

Tags: django, django-oscar

I have created a form that allows a user to modify a `Product`'s `ProductClass`. However, after I save the product, its `ProductAttributeValues` are automatically duplicated and stored. Here is a simple example of the process:

```
product = Product.objects.first()
product.product_class = ProductClass.objects.get(pk=2)
product.save()
```

Imagine that the product initially belonged to a `ProductClass` with pk=1 and that it had a single `ProductAttribute` named started with a `ProductAttributeValue` set to `True`. After executing the three lines above, a new `ProductAttributeValue` of started also set to `True` was automatically generated and stored. Is there a simple way to avoid this behavior? Is this how a `Product`'s `ProductClass` should be modified?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you've written code to duplicate attributes on save, and now you don't want it to do that, then remove that code, surely?

Comment: Daniel you are absolutely right. I meant to say `ProductAttributeValues`. The `ProductAttribute` records did not change. I am editing my question.